# Latex - How to define commands macros the save way

Tags: macros

Using: Latex -> pdfLatex, and also loading another tex file written by me with:

```
\input{\myPath anotherDocument.tex}
%% there is a "private" macro:
\def\foo#1{$\backslash$def$\backslash$#1$\{$the name$\}$}
%% doesn't compile without $

%% all happens before
\begin{document}
```

1) Why can't I define the macro JUST like others ? Because all other macros are defined without $ but also contain commands like\foo{}.
2) What does $ do ?
3) What does * do ?
4) Why do some packages influence each other ?
5) Why is the Latex syntax inconsistent ?
6) What is wrong with Latex ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'm afraid ranting about LaTeX in a LaTeX community won't raise the probability of you getting helpful answers. As it stands, neither your example nor the formulation of your questions allows to understand what the problem really is. Please try to pose one question at a time and describe precisely what is happening and what you want to happen. If you really don't know what `$` does, it is adviseable to read a basic introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: The StackeExchange model works best with one query per question. As @StephanLehmke says, a rant about (La)TeX (however justified) will not help you get answers.

Answer (score 7):

- Nothing is wrong with LaTeX.
- The syntax of LaTeX may not be the best, but it is consistent.
- Packages influence each other because it's the way software works.
- `*` prints an asterisk; but in some cases, put after a command modifies its behavior.
- `$` enters math mode, for typesetting math formulas
- You *can* define your `\foo` macro in a safe way. Just don't try *typesetting* backslashes.

---

You want that

```
\foo{xyz}
```

executes

```
\def\xyz{the name}
```

Thus you have to add a backslash to the argument or, better, to form a symbolic token with that name. This is available by `\csname...\endcsname` or, in the LaTeX kernel, by `\@namedef`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{\@namedef{#1}{the name}}
\makeatother
```

This is quite easy, isn't it?

What you did was to define

```
\foo{xyz}
```

to produce

```
$\backslash$def$\backslash$xyz$\{$the name$\}$
```

which is good for *printing* something, not for definitions.